# Continue looping after a given iterator position in an std::map

Tags: c++

I want to loop over all items of a map that follow a given item.

Unfortunately, I get the error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'std::_Rb_tree_iterator >' and 'int').

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main ()
{
  std::map<char,int> m = {
    {'a',1},{'b',2},{'c',3},{'d',4},
  };

  // Position at 'b' (the 'given item')
  auto it = m.find('b');

  // Output everything after 'b':
  for (auto it1=it+1; it1!=m.end(); ++it1) {
    std::cout << it1->first << " => " << it1->second << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (auto it1=it+1; it1!=m.end(); ++it1) {` in case `it` already points to `end()` the condition may fail due to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iterator for a `std::map` is not random-access, so it doesn't have an `operator+()`.  You need to use `std::next()` instead:

```
 for (auto it1=std::next(it); it1!=m.end(); ++it1) {
    std::cout << it1->first << " => " << it1->second << '\n';
 }
```

Comment: If I see it correctly, you were 26 seconds earlier then Raw N... -> you get the "solved". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`++` works just as well:

```
 // Output everything after 'b':
    for (auto it1=++it; it1!=m.end(); ++it1) {
      std::cout << it1->first << " => " << it1->second << '\n';
    }
```